# How to you select a text field

Tags: ios, uitextfield

I have a table view with two rows, both of which have `UITextFields` in them. I also added the `UITextFieldDelegate` protocol and the `-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField` method to the table view controller file.

I can detect when the return key is pressed on the first text field, but how do I make it automatically move to the second text field?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
[textField becomeFirstResponder];
```